# Move from one web host to another but keep Google Email Settings

Tags: web-hosting, migration, mx, google-domains, a-record

Web host: Hostinger

Domain from Google Domains
MX Records for Googledomains (Nameservers:4 records starting with: NS-CLOUD-E1.Googledomains.com. ALL 4 are to cloud.googledomains.com)

New Web host : Bluehost

Website: Built on Wordpress

Simply want to migrate WP website away from Hostinger to Bluehost.
Want to leave ALL MX RECORDS untouched and on Googledomains.

Question: Am I correct that the simple solution after the migration process is to ONLY change the A record at Googledomains currently pointing to Hostinger IP address and instead point it to Bluehost given IP address?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The A Record tells the internet where the site is located.  If you don't change the nameservers and leave the MX records (which we assume are working) then simply updating the A Record will do the job.